# How to parse array with no label

Tags: ansible

Given the following output, how do I check for empty array?

```
ok: [10.102.11.12] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            {
                "foo": "bar"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "test": "yes"
            }
        ],
        []
    ]
}
```

I have something like this but I get an error: `FAILED! => {"msg": "list object has no element ()"}`

```
  - name: test
    debug: msg="{{foo}}"
    failed_when: item|length==0
    with_items: "{{foo.msg[]}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

<sup>(ansible 2.8.3)</sup>

Simple `when` condition should do the job. The task below

```
- debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ my_output }}"
  when: item|length > 0
```

gives

```
"item": [
    {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
]

"item": [
    {
        "test": "yes"
    }
]
```

---

Notes

1) Empty index `msg[]` is the reason of the error

> FAILED! => {"msg": "list object has no element ()"}